# Updating value in Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am currently working on a spacecraft body with actuator, and given the equation below:

```
J·w_dot = -w^x·J·w + u                                 (1)
```

where `w^x` is actually a notation of 3x3 matrix

```
[  0 -w3  w2 
  w3   0 -w1 
 -w2  w1   0]
```

By rearranging (1), I got `w_dot = (-w^x·J·w + u)/J`. And here I face the problem, I need to update value constantly for `w_dot` but I have no idea how. I have tried the <kbd>Memory</kbd> block but it only update every 0.2 seconds which is not appropriate for the system.

This is my current setting:

[image]

I was thinking the <kbd>integrator</kbd> block could be the one to be updated every single cycle as initial condition could be set.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your solution seems about right; the integrator block will cause the system to be continuous-time, rather than discrete-time. This will output results as accurately as Simulink can accomplish.

You can set initial values for the <kbd>integrator</kbd> by double-clicking on the integrator block, setting the "`Initial condition source`" to "`external`", then connecting another input or <kbd>constant</kbd> block, output, or whatever else you want providing the initial value.

By the way, is `J` is the [inertia tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia)? In that case, you can't simply "divide" by it; you should multiply by its inverse (setting "`Matrix`" as the "`Multiplication`" option in the <kbd>Divide</kbd> block's options)